# TFS Cloned need to clear all mappings

Tags: .net, tfs

I've just upgraded/cloned our TFS 2012 server to a new machine running 2018 SP1.  However, all the workspaces were cloned as well and the mappings still exist.  Is there a way to remove all the mappings in the DB so all users need to create new mapping for this new server?

I don't want anyone to overwrite their existing code...

Comment: I see workspace tables in SQL server but I'm not sure if it's safe to just wipe them...

Answer (score 2):

It's not suggested to delete files in database. You could use [Workspaces Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspaces-command) to display the list of all workspaces for all users on all computers that have been created. For example:

```
c:\projects>tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Then, use `tf workspaces /remove` Command to remove all cached workspaces from the cache in the team project collection. For example:

```
c:\projects>tf workspaces /remove:* /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Comment: So that doesn't actually help.  I can't remove workspaces for other people.  And according to the docs, it only clears the cache on the local machine.  I need to force everyone to re-map.

Comment: @Sam, Use [tf workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspace-command) to delete all workspaces: `tf workspace /delete /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl "workspacename;workspaceowner"`

Comment: So to be clear, to delete all workspaces for all users, I would need to write a script that iterates through each and executes that command, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's safer than deleting database. Here is an example script to delete workspaces for your reference: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Script-to-Delete-All-83ab2ec0